# CheckStyle plugin for IDEA - java way of warnings presentation and automatic fixes?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, checkstyle

1. Is it possible to make it present the list of warnings java/spellchecker style as opposed to a old school list of errors with line numbers?
2. Can it automatically fix things like missed space near '=' etc?

Maybe I need a different plugin, which one then?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try **QAPlug** - Checkstyle plugin. Then go Analyze - Analyze Code (not the standard Analyze!) then click "..." near Run with chosen profile select a concrete profile and press the import button.

[image]

In the next dialog select the checkstyle rules file and then click the OK button. That's it. Just wait for the results. I got something like this.

[image]

That plugin has its limitations however. For example, I didn't manage to use a file with suppressions with it.

You can also use the plugin **CheckStyle-IDEA** which also has good configurations and allows you to use *suppressions*, *custom checks* and displays the inspection warnings in the editor immediately, but to apply that you need to set Project Settings - Inspections - CheckStyle - Real-Time Scan in the IDE settins.

[image]

[image]

Answering the second question, I didn't find any automatical reformat capabilities in these plugins, just checks.