# Edit Checkstyle rules within Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, checkstyle

Is there a way within intellij that the checkstyle rules can be edited?  Within the Eclipse checkstyle plugin you can edit specific rules within the IDE, is their a similar plugin for Intellij? I tried downloading idea-checkstyle and QA-Plug plugins, but these don't seem to be able to edit the checkstyle xml file directly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CheckStyle plugin for IDEA - java way of warnings presentation and automatic fixes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229217/checkstyle-plugin-for-idea-java-way-of-warnings-presentation-and-automatic-fix)

Answer (score 2):

We don't support this in Checkstyle-IDEA and have no plans to implement this. Sorry.